# Sequelize nodejs guidance about raw query conversion to model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to `sequelize` and I have given tasks to change `sequelize` **raw queries to ORM** and I am confused in so many things. I will provide a sample query with associations if anyone can help please take me out of this pain. Thanks

```
db.sequelize.query('SELECT id, username, full_name, profile_image_url, ' +
    '(SELECT COUNT(*) from public."Followships" WHERE public."Followships".leader_id = :user_id) AS followers, ' +
    '(SELECT COUNT(*) from public."Followships" WHERE public."Followships".follower_id = :user_id) AS following, ' +
    '(SELECT array_agg(interest_id) from public."UserInterestsMaps" WHERE public."UserInterestsMaps".user_id = :user_id) AS user_interests, ' +
    'FROM public."Users" ' +
    'where public."Users".id = :user_id', { replacements: { user_id: req.params.user_id }, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
```

Association of **Followship** with the **User** table

```
Followship.belongsTo(models.User, {
  as: 'followings',
  foreignKey: 'leader_id',
  foreignKeyConstraint: true
});
Followship.belongsTo(models.User, {
  as: 'followers',
  foreignKey: 'follower_id',
  foreignKeyConstraint: true
});
```

I am trying to understand `sequelize` but it is not that much straight forward.

Comment: I think you shouldn't worry so much about translating queries at first. If you have defined your models and the relations between them, the queries they'll run underneath when you use their methods will practically be the same. So, have you defined your "Users", "UserInterestMaps"? a User has many followers. a User can also have many followings. So there is a many-to-many relationship. Did you look up how many-to-many-relationships are implemented?

Comment: Thanks, @aec for replying. Your words are no doubt so much help but I need an example or maybe a sample code or link that can help me further. Ahaaa okay, I was thinking in a different direction now I will search about the many-to-many relationship implementation. Thanks

Comment: cheers. Once you get it working, you should write an answer here with your code so others who have the same problem in the future can learn from it.

Comment: Thanks, @aec. Now I am getting the tempo and understanding the associations (y)